# MariaDB incorrectly saves values with accent from Docker

Tags: docker, mariadb

Good morning, I generate the database with this initial script, but the word **CRÉDITOS** incorrectly saved with the value **CRÃ‰DITOS**.

Script sql/script.sql

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    COD_PRODUCTO VARCHAR(5),
    NOM_PRODUCTO VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (COD_PRODUCTO )
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

INSERT INTO DB_CLIENTES_POTENCIALES.my_table
VALUES ('yy', 'CRÉDIOS');
```

Docker build

```
docker build -f GenerarMariaDb.Dockerfile -t clientespotencialesmariadb_image:latest .
```

Docker run

```
docker run --env-file=clientes-potenciales-mariadb.env -d -p 3306:3306 --name clientespotencialesmariadb clientespotencialesmariadb_image:latest --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

Docker file

```
FROM mariadb:latest

ADD sql/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

#RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install vim

EXPOSE 3306

CMD ["mysqld"]
```

Docker env

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=XXXX
MYSQL_DATABASE=DB_CLIENTES
MYSQL_USER=XXXX
MYSQL_PASSWORD=XXXX
```

Record saved with wrong encoding

[image]

Could someone point out to me that I'm forgetting?

Thanks you!

Comment: See 'Mojibake' in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)